# Access an inner function from outside the function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access an inner function from outside a function in Javascript, but it only prints "undefined" instead of printing the function's source code. How can I modify the prototype of the function `changeBlah` from outside the scope of `exampleFunction`?

```
var blah = "";
function exampleFunction(theParameter){
   this.blah = theParameter;
    this.changeBlah = function(){
        this.blah += "gah";
    }
}

var stuff2 = new exampleFunction("Heh!");
alert(stuff2.blah);
stuff2.changeBlah();
alert(stuff2.blah);

alert(exampleFunction.changeBlah); //now why doesn't this work? It doesn't print the function's source code, but instead prints undefined.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: I just realized that replacing `exampleFunction.changeBlah` with `stuff2.changeBlah` prints the function's source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is by using the Prototype model:

```
function exampleFunction(theParameter) {this.blah = theParameter;}
exampleFunction.prototype.changeBlah = function() {this.blah += "gah";}

alert(exampleFunction.prototype.changeBlah);
```

Answer (score 0):

> .. now why doesn't [exampleFunction.changeBlah] work?

Because `this` *was not* `exampleFunction`.

It was a *new object* which had `exampleFunction` as the [[prototype]]. Assigning to a property *does not* propagate back up the [[prototype]] resolution chain. (There is *no way* to access the [[prototype]] of an object directly from an object, but if the [[prototype]] object is *known* then it can be *mutated*.)

Compare with (this will break `stuff2.blah`, but should show `exampleFunction.changeBlah` working as expected):

```
exampleFunction.changeBlah = function(){
    this.blah += "gah";
}
```

(Also see xdazz's comment for another possible access method.)

Comment: As the [[constructor]] i think.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution that I've devised so far (and it's reasonably concise):

```
exampleFunction.prototype.changeBlah = function(){
    this.blah += "gah"; //"this" refers to an instance of changeBlah, apparently 
}

var blah = "";
function exampleFunction(theParameter){
   this.blah = theParameter;
}

var stuff2 = new exampleFunction("Heh!");
alert(stuff2.blah);
stuff2.changeBlah(); //it works, even though the "prototype" keyword isn't specifically used here
alert(stuff2.blah);
alert(exampleFunction.prototype.changeBlah);​
```